# How do I wrap text in DDX

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, itext

I have dynamic content i'm outputting in a Footer element in a PDF w/ DDX & Coldfusion.  Some of the records have long text, and do not automatically wrap, I have placed

tags, tried padding/margin, all to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy with `<cfdocument format="PDF">`.  Maybe have org.pdf converted into an image using the make thumbnail action, then use cfdocument and HTML to style the footer?  Not most efficient, but easiest.